# Pointer arithmetic and accessing values using pointers in C (BMP image as example)

Tags: c

I am learning C language and after some days now I am thinking to learn image processing and I started with BMP images and found many tutorials like *How to read and write BMP image with C program* but I have some doubts in my mind.

This line in code `int width = *(int*)&header[18]`

Yes I know what is happening in above code but what about 19,20 and 21 byte ? 18 byte is enough for width ? We can get width by just getting the content of 18 element ?

Comment: BITMAPHEADER is fully documented. Did you try a google search for it?

Comment: Yes but I am confused with arrays representation of header

Comment: `&header[18]` is an address. You could write it as `(header + 18)`.

Comment: you need to learn about how pointer arithmetic as well as how referencing a memory location with different *basic type* pointers works in C. This question has nothing to do with BMPs it has to do with pointer arithmetic.   Also, you actually *don't know* what's happening at that line — otherwise you wouldn't post a question about it :-) just sayin'

Comment: This code is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) (strict aliasing violation). Anything may happen,  a reasonably common manifestation of this UB is to read four bytes. Any tutorial featuring this code is rubbish

Comment: This seems like it may also fail on platforms which don't support unaligned access, if `&header[18]` is not aligned to a multiple of your platform's word size.

Comment: In addition to the strict aliasing issue, using `int` to express 4 raw byte values is also rubbish. You need to use unsigned types.

Comment: Further study for the people who wrote the "tutorial": [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is taking the address of the 18. byte and then reads a 4 byte long integer at that address, so it does read byte 19, 20 and 21 as well.

- `header` is a pointer to the place in memory where the BMP header is stored in bytes
- `header[18]` means the same as `*(header + 18)`, we add 18 to the address and read the value at that address, tha `*` operator so called *dereferences* the pointer
- `&header[18]`: take the address of that value, same as `header + 18`, but some people find this form more expressive
- `(int*)&header[18]`: so far we worked with `char*` pointers (pointers that point to memory that hold values type of `char`), now we cast this pointer to an `int` pointer, this doesn't modify anything in the memory, it just changes the way we interpret the data underlying the pointer
- `*(int*)&header[18]`: dereference the `int*` to get the value of the integer at the `header + 18` memory address, and since `int` is 4 byte long on your platform, this will result in loading 4 bytes into the variable `width`

So we could simplify the expression like this: `*(int*)(header + 18)`. This way its not as misleading and easy to be mistaken for only reading 1 bytes.

The reason we need to cast `header` to an `int*` is because the type of `header` is `char*`, dereferencing that would really only read a single byte.

Comment: You have a good answer, please expand your answer a bit more to show a working example.

Comment: @krisz Nice explanation thnx now I am able to understand the all logic :)

Comment: `*(int*)&header[18]` creates a strict aliasing violation, and even if it didn't, it will write data into the sign bit of the int. Similarly, `char` cannot be used for bitmaps since it has implementation-defined signedness. This is 3 different fatal bugs.